# ¿Cómo poner una raíz cuadrada en legend Matlab?

Tags: matlab

Buenas, tengo una gráfica hecha en Matlab y me gustaría escribir una función analítica en la leyenda, que incluye una raíz cuadrada. Me gustaría saber si hay alguna manera de que me imprima el símbolo de la raíz cuadrada en la leyenda.
Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Si conoces el lenguaje Latex puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
xlabel('$\sqrt{}$','Interpreter','Latex')
```

En caso contrario no hace falta, con poner la ecuación entre $ y saber que la raiz es \sqrt{} es suficiente.